# Javascript Table cell value reader doesn't get values from .net Repeater

Tags: javascript, repeater, dynamic-data

I have JS function that read and summarize table column like that:

```
function calculateValue() {
        var sum = 0, index = 0;
        var table = document.getElementById("mytab1");
        for (var i = 1, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
            //alert(row.cells[4].firstChild.nodeValue);
            sum += row.cells[4].firstChild.nodeValue;
            index++;
        }
        //alert(sum / index + "_" + sum + "--" + index);
        return sum / index;
    }
```

This Table ("mytab1") is a dynamic table, a .net C# repeater build this table.
when I try to alert the values, only the table header works, the other values are empty although there are values inside of them.
Any Ideas why?

my page load function is:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        load_profiles();
        ViewState["Time"] = "2";                   
        LoadGoals(2,0); /* this function put List<> in Repeater and creates a table   
                           with the values */          
    }
}
```

The js part that calls the function:

> var def = {
>               percentage: **calculateValue()** || 0,
>               scale: 100,
>               limit: true,
>               minimum: 0,
>               maximum: 100,
>               suffix: ' %',
>               animate: true,
>               digitalRoll: true,
>               thisCss: {
>                   position: 'relative', 
>                   width: '105px',
>                   height: '90px',
>                   padding: '0px',
>                   border: '0px',
>                   fontFamily: 'Arial',
>                   fontWeight: '250',

```
        },
```

When the function alert in the table search loop, i can see the values inside the table, and also the Column header is alerting with his value.
Thanks.

Comment: When do you call the calculateValue function in your code?

Comment: I'd like to help out more, but I think you need to add a little more detail about the problem you are attempting to fix.  I assume by speedometer you're referring to [this](http://plugins.jquery.com/node/14397/release).  My suspicion is that you are calling your javascript function before the table is done loading.  If you could provide more code snippets about where you're calling this speedometer api and how your page is set-up, it would help a lot.

Comment: i've added all of the relevant code. the strange thing is that i already see the values in the html and still can't get to them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest making sure that where you call your javascript:

```
var def = {
percentage: calculateValue() || 0, scale: 100, limit: true, minimum: 0, maximum: 100, suffix: ' %', animate: true, digitalRoll: true, thisCss: { position: 'relative', width: '105px', height: '90px', padding: '0px', border: '0px', fontFamily: 'Arial', fontWeight: '250',
    },
```

is either a) after the

```
<asp:Repeater></asp:Repeater>
```

control, or b) add a

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// Your code goes here
});
```

bit of JQuery to your page to make sure that the DOM has been fully loaded before you try to read the values from the table.

**EDIT:**

You may also want to use a JQuery selector to access and sum the values instead of using your loop.

```
var sum = 0;
$('#mytab1 .your-new-table-cell-class').each(function() {
    sum += Number($(this).val());
    });
});​​​​​​​​​
```